# How to insert n-1 column values in oracle database table

Tags: sql, oracle, insert-into

I have 2 tables Tab1 and Tab2.Both have same columns except that Tab2 has one additional column than Tab1.Now I want to insert data from Tab2 into Tab1.

- Tab1:col1,col2.....col100
- Tab2:col1,col2.....col100,col101

How can i achieve this.

I do not want to mention column names during insert.

Can this be done.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't be lazy, specify all columns(as in Gordon's answer).That is the right thing to do. It will benefit you as well the people who inherit your code.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I think Software development ( like the other aspects of Technology ) mostly inspired by idea of laziness. A lazy man maybe more productive and creative than the others.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan : Yes, I totally agree with your statement. But I'm  not convinced that it can be  a valid justification for the OP's case and I wouldn't like any more arguments :-)

Comment: @KaushikNayak OK :)

Answer (score 5):

You list all the columns:

```
insert into table1(col1, . . ., col100)
    select col1, . . . , col100
    from table2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the update.
I donot want to specify col names in insert and select

Comment: @satya, what Gordon suggests, is bug-free solution and known as "best practice". If you don't want to specify columns - build up dynamic sql (universal insert statement from user_%, dba_% tables)

Comment: I don't believe this is the right answer for this question. OP wants to get more dynamic way.

Answer (score 2):

```
alter table tab1 add additional_column_from_tab2
```

Now you can use bad practice and

```
insert into tab1 select * From tab2
```

Comment: You forgot to add "...and after the INSERT you can `ALTER TABLE TAB1 DROP COLUMN ADDITIONAL_COLUMN_FROM_TAB2`". But +1 for creative way to Do The Wrong Thing. :-)

Answer (score 2):

OK, let's go full-in here.

Let's use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE
  strStmt  VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  strStmt := 'INSERT INTO TAB1 SELECT ';

  FOR aRow IN (SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TAB1') LOOP
    strStmt := strStmt || aRow.COLUMN_NAME || ',';
  END LOOP;  -- aRow

  strStmt := SUBSTR(strStmt, 1, LENGTH(strStmt)-1) || ' FROM TAB2';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strStmt;
END;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5ad11/3)

Fits all your requirements. Inserts data from TAB2 into TAB1 without mentioning the name of one single column in either table in the code.

Best of luck.

Comment: Need to give a try

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It can be done by using `user_tab_columns` dictionary view as in the following :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> 
SQL> create table table1(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int);

Table created
SQL> create table table2(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int, col5 int);

Table created

SQL> insert into table2 values(1,2,3,4,5);

1 row inserted

SQL> declare
  2    v_sql  varchar2(4000) := 'insert into TABLE1 ';
  3    v_tab  varchar2(40)   := 'TABLE2';
  4  begin
  5    for c in ( select column_name, column_id
  6                from
  7                (
  8                select t.column_name,
  9                       t.column_id,
 10                       max(t.column_id)
 11                        over ( order by t.table_name ) max_col_id
 12                  from user_tab_columns t
 13                 where t.table_name = v_tab
 14                )
 15               where column_id < max_col_id )
 16    loop
 17     if c.column_id = 1 then
 18      v_sql := v_sql||'select '||c.column_name;
 19     else
 20      v_sql := v_sql||','||c.column_name;
 21     end if;
 22    end loop;
 23      v_sql := v_sql||' from '||v_tab;
 24      dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
 25      execute immediate v_sql;
 26      commit;
 27  end;
 28  /

insert into TABLE1 select COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4 from TABLE2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> select * from table1;

COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
---- ---- ---- ----
   1    2    3    4
```

Comment: This script is executing as excepted.
Thank you so much:)